# Why do we signify particular aspect if parabrahman has all aspects?

Tags: brahman, saraswati

Let us consider Ma Saraswathi for this question. The following are some of the sloka and [names](https://www.drikpanchang.com/hindu-names/goddesses/saraswati/1000-saraswati-names.html) for the Saraswathi

> [śaradiṃdu samākāre **parabrahma svarūpiṇ**e vāsarā pīṭha nilaye
> sarasvatī namostute](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/34915/661)
>
> ॐ शिवायै नमः।   Om Shivayai Namah। (125)
>
> ॐ सर्वैश्वर्य प्रदायै नमः। Om Sarvaishvarya Pradayai Namah। (190)
>
> ॐ ब्रह्माण्डाधिप वल्लभायै नमः। Om Brahmandadhipa Vallabhayai Namah।
> (515)
>
> ॐ ब्रह्मेश विष्णुरूपायै नमः। Om Brahmesha Vishnurupayai Namah। (516)
>
> ॐ ब्रह्मविष्ण्वीश संस्थितायै नमः। Om Brahmavishnvisha Samsthitayai
> Namah। (517)

It is obvious from the mentions that Saraswathi is parabrahman. She is in the form of Shiva, Vishnu and Brahma. She is moksha vidya.

But whenever we read or hear about her, she is signified as the goddess of knowledge, learning, etc., instead of the complete parabrahman. Even scriptures praise her in these aspects generally.

The name #190 says that she can give any wealth. But, whenever people want wealth, they (generally) pray to Lakshmi even though Saraswathi can bestow wealth.

What is the *need or reason for signifying particular aspects* of parabrahman even though she can bestow anything and everything?

Comment: Yes, that should be the case, if not then there will be a denomination of Divinities in Sanatana Culture. Else the concept of Ishvara and Deva, and all Vedic concepts like Narayana and Manyu will go into chaos.

Answer (score 0):

Let us look at Sri Ramakrishna's explanation.

> "Do you know what I mean? Think of Brahman, Existence-Knowledge- Bliss
> Absolute, as a shoreless ocean. **Through the cooling influence, as it
> were, of the bhakta's love, the water has frozen at places into blocks
> of ice. In other words, God now and then assumes various forms for His
> lovers and reveals Himself to them as a Person.** But with the rising of
> the sun of Knowledge, the blocks of ice melt. Then one doesn't feel
> any more that God is a Person, nor does one see God's forms. What He
> is cannot be described. Who will describe Him? He who would do so
> disappears. He cannot find his 'I' any more.

**The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Chapter 6,The Master with Brahmo Devotees (I)**

The different aspects, like the icebergs of the ocean, are for devotees. It is impossible to have devotion for Nirguna Brahman. The methods adopted for attaining Nirguna Brahman are 'neti neti' and 'who am I?'.

It is only possible to have bhakti for an aspect of Brahman. Even the mantras reflect that. Take a look at the very first mantra 'Om Shivayai Namah'. Om is all and represents the infinite. The mantra means 'Salutation to the Shiva aspect of Om'.

Comment: But why can't Saraswathi can have devotees towards the wealth aspect?

Comment: Because Scripture asks devotees to worship different deities to get different aspects. I am giving one example from Srimad Bhagavata Purana II.3.2-3: Sri Suka said, "One who desires to have the lustre of Vedic learning should adore Brahma from whom the Vedas have come; those who seek power of the senses should worship Indra, and those who desire progeny, the Prajapatis. The seeker of wealth should worship Sri Devi; of brilliance, the deity Agni; of wealth, the Vasus; and of power, the Rudras. The seekers of food stuffs should worship Aditi; of heaven....................